# How can I display a column per record in Crystal Reports instead of a row per record?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a dataset that has records like this:

```
Amount | Discount | Charge | Potential
21,123 | 8,800    | 0      | 3,500
22,123 | 8,500    | 1,100  | 3,800
```

In a Crystal Report, I would like this to be displayed like this:

```
         Client 1  Client 2  Combined
Amount    21,123    22,123    43,246
Discount   8,800     8,500    17,300
Charge         0     1,100     1,100
Potential  3,500     3,800     7,300
```

I have obviously searched quite a bit before asking the question but could not find a simple way to do this. I have fiddled a bit with Cross-Tabs but could not get the result I wanted either.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What didn't work with a cross tab? That will give you exactly what you need.

Comment: Hi, dotjoe. I was getting totals on the left side of the table and could not get rid of them. Could someone walk me through exactly what I would need to get a cross tab looking like what I need? Thank you!

Comment: To remove row totals to left you need to uncheck the option `Row totals to left` from `customize style` of `cross tab expert`

Comment: I've tried that but the totals are still there, not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Use crosstab, it is the analog of pivot table in Excel

Comment: I've tried but could not get it to look like I wanted it to. I've now pivoted the data itself and I'm displaying it the "normal" way in the report. Still curious as to how to use a cross tab properly.